# Remove double quoted string from text file?

Tags: bash, shell, vim, sed, sh

I'm working on some text files, i have to remove a specific string

```
ex: "1234_NAME=TRUE", (including double quotes and comma)
```

Using Vim editor if i pass

```
:%s/"1234_NAME=TRUE",//g
```

But In this way i will be doing manually. But i want to automate the job by using some script.

I tried using sed tool, but it failed.

```
sed 's/"1234_NAME=TRUE",//g' hello.txt
```

I'm not expert on scripting. i know command is not correct. what is the solution for the above command.

And one more question:

Instead of passing file names manually, can we add a small loop which will take all text files in a directory one by one and remove the string.

Answer as suggested by @codeforester require some fix:

```
for file in *.txt
do
   [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue
```

semicolon was the issue.

and Thanks to @SlePort for the answer.

Regards,

GBiradar

Comment: sed command is correct just use `sed -i.bak`

Comment: Yes i added -i it worked. But i have to process one file at a time i tried using for loop as mentioned by @codeforester but it didn't worked.

Comment: Got it. I have to fix @codeforester answer. it worked.

Comment: What was the issue in my answer?  Please update it accordingly.

Comment: `for ...; do` is another way of writing `for ...` and then `do` on the next line.  It's not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i.bak 's/"1234_NAME=TRUE",//g' *.txt
```

- `-i` for *in place* editing
- `.bak`: the extension of the backed up files

Comment: While `-i` isn't standard, it isn't specific to GNU `sed` either.

Answer (score 2):

Your command is correct.  To loop through your files, you can use a simple loop:

```
for file in *.txt; do          # assuming your files are have .txt extension, modify accordingly
  [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue # skip if not a regular file
  sed 's/"1234_NAME=TRUE",//g' "$file" > "$file.modified" && mv "$file.modified" "$file"
  # you can also use the `-i` flag to make a backup of the file and then overwrite the original
  # `-i ''` will skip the backup and just overwrite the file
  # sed -i .bak 's/"1234_NAME=TRUE",//g' "$file"
done
```

Make sure you have a backup of your files before running the above code.